Input cell going into in an infinite loop
When rapidly clicking on the increment/decrement arrow in the Tab 2 numeric input cell, it frequently goes into an infinite loop. I think it is related to how reactive values are treated in the RenderUI part, however, I cannot figure out how to solve this given I need a functionality to retain user inputted values when switching between objects, i.e., there is circularity. What is further confusing is that this behaviour is not consistent and sometimes the app works just fine.
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(2, selectInput("objSel", "Select Object:", choices = c("Object 1"), selected = "Object 1")),
    column(2, actionButton("addObject", "Add Object", class = "btn-primary", style = "margin-top: 25px;"))
  ),
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Tab 1", fluidRow(
      column(6, 
             matrixInput(
               inputId = "tab1_table",
               value = matrix(),
               rows = list(names = FALSE),
               cols = list(names = TRUE),
               class = c("character", "numeric")
             )
      )
    )
    ),
    tabPanel("Tab 2", fluidRow( uiOutput("tab2_settings") )
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  reactive_values <- reactiveValues(
    objects = list("Object 1"=list(
      tab1_table = matrix(c("", "", 0, 0), 
                          nrow = 2, 
                          ncol = 2,
                          dimnames = list(NULL, c("Name", "Value"))),
      tab2_inputs = list(tables = list(), charts = list())
    )),  # Store objects dynamically
    tab1_table = NULL,
    tab2_inputs = NULL
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$addObject, {
    # Determine a new object ID
    object_id <- length(reactive_values$objects) + 1
    object_name <- paste("Object", object_id)
    
    # Add new object to reactive values
    reactive_values$objects[[object_name]] <- list(
      
      tab1_table = input$tab1_table,
      tab2_inputs       = input$tab2_inputs
      
    )
    
    # Update dropdown with new object
    updateSelectInput(session, "objSel", choices = c(names(reactive_values$objects)), selected = object_name)
    
  })
  
  # Synchronize Inputs on Object Selection
  observeEvent(input$objSel, {
    
    req(input$objSel)
    selected_object <- reactive_values$objects[[input$objSel]]
    updateMatrixInput (session, "tab1_table", value = selected_object$tab1_table)
    
  })
  
  # Save Inputs to the Selected Object Dynamically
  observe({
    
    req(input$objSel)
    
    selected_object <- reactive_values$objects[[input$objSel]]
    
    reactive_values$objects[[input$objSel]]$tab1_table <- input$tab1_table
    
    for(table_id in names(selected_object$tab2_inputs$tables)){
      
      items <- c('_input1','_input2')
      
      for(item_id in 1:length(items)){
        
        if (!is.null(input[[paste0(input$objSel, "_", table_id, items[item_id])]])) {
          
          reactive_values$objects[[input$objSel]]$tab2_inputs$tables[[table_id]]$Category[item_id] <- input[[paste0(input$objSel, "_", table_id, items[item_id])]]
          
        }
        
      }
      
    }
    
  })
  
  # Render UI
  output$tab2_settings <- renderUI({
    
    req(input$objSel)
    selected_object <- reactive_values$objects[[input$objSel]]
    no_table_row <- nrow(selected_object$tab1_table)
    no_tab2_panel <- length(selected_object$tab2_inputs$tables)
    
    # Ensure no of tables matches no of rows
    while(no_table_row>no_tab2_panel){
      
      table_id <- paste0("table_", length(reactive_values$objects[[input$objSel]]$tab2_inputs$tables) + 1)
      
      reactive_values$objects[[input$objSel]]$tab2_inputs$tables[[table_id]] <- data.frame(Category <- c('Choice 1', 5))
      
      no_tab2_panel <- no_tab2_panel + 1
      
    }
    
    selected_object <- reactive_values$objects[[input$objSel]]
    
    tables_ui <- lapply(names(selected_object$tab2_inputs$tables), function(table_id){
      
      current_table <- selected_object$tab2_inputs$tables[[table_id]]
      
      column(3,  # Each table occupies 1/4 of a row
             div(class = "input-chart-wrapper",
                 div(class = "compact-layout",
                     h5(paste("Table:", table_id)),
                     
                     fluidRow(
                       column(12, selectInput(paste0(input$objSel, "_", table_id, "_input1"), "Input 1",
                                              choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3"),
                                              selected = current_table$Category[1]))
                     ),
                     
                     fluidRow(
                       column(12, numericInput(paste0(input$objSel, "_", table_id, "_input2"), "Input 2",
                                               value = current_table$Category[2], 
                                               step = 1
                       ))
                     )
                     
                 )
             )
      )
      
    })
    
    # Arrange tables and charts in a 2-row by 4-column grid
    grid <- tagList()
    n_tables <- length(tables_ui)
    rows <- ceiling(n_tables / 4)
    
    for (row in 1:rows) {
      grid <- tagAppendChildren(grid, fluidRow( tables_ui[((row - 1) * 4 + 1):min(row * 4, n_tables)] ))
    }
    
    grid
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


You have shared 162 lines of code to ask for help. Your code is reproducible but it is not minimal. Please keep only the details that are required to reproduce the error.
